# Why does splitting a string return a (bad) value across multiple lines in my Rails API application, but not the console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a GrapeSwaggerRails API application that takes a two dates and a comma-delimited string of category IDs. It should query the database for Records with a `created_at` within the two given dates and a `category_id` that matches one of the IDs passed to it. I'm not having any trouble with the dates, so I'll skip that for now. But let's say I want Records with categories matching 8, 2, or 1. In the code, it looks like `"8,2,1"`. In the URL, it gets appended as `&categories=%228%2C2%2C1%22`.

Anyway, I figured one decent way of getting this to do what I want would be to convert that string into an array of integers like this: `categories = params[:categories].split(',').map(&:to_i)`

But given `"8,2,1"`, the output is this (ignore the comment):

```
0 # <-- ?????
2
1
```

Very strange. In the definition of the API, `params[:categories]` looks like this: `"8,2,1"`. But `params[:categories].split(',')` becomes the following:

```
"8
2
1"
```

That's a bit odd, isn't it? Running the `map` method on that turns it into that nonsense higher up, converting the `"8` to a `0` for reasons I'm hoping to find out here. I know I could probably come at this problem from a different angle and sidestep the issue, but I'd rather try to get to the root of what's going wrong, so I can learn something from it. For reference, here's what the Rails console does when I put (as far as I can tell) the same data into it:

```
>> "8,2,1".split(',')
#=> ["8", "2", "1"]
```

`map` then works as expected.

```
>> "8,2,1".split(',').map(&:to_i)
#=> [8, 2, 1]
```

So my question is twofold. What's going wrong with this split function? Why does it behave differently in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `params[:categories]` is actually

```
'"8,2,1"' # <- the outer ''s are just for illustration of a string.
```

If you pass `&categories=8%2C2%2C1` it should work as expected.

Comment: This is one of the dumbest things I've seen in my entire career. I had to chomp the god damn quotation marks off. Wow! Thanks.

Comment: @VGambit The truly dumb thing is how the quotes got there in the first place.